# How to conditionally set REDIRECT_URI in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am configuring auth function on Firebase to authenticate users. 
While running localhost I set the following:

```
const OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:4200/callback`
```

On production I need the function to call `https://mywebsite.com` instead of `localhost`. 
How can I set this?

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure some variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) that will be deployed with the function, and you can change those per project.  They can then be accessed at runtime.

Set them on the command line:

```
firebase functions:config:set auth.uri="..."
```

Then access it in code:

```
functions.config().auth.uri
```

Comment: but again, this will require a different project. The question is, how do I do it on the same project, but different environment (localhost/prod)

Comment: It's recommended that each environment have its own project.  "localhost" is not really an environment.  Minimally, people have different projects for development and production.